# jsPDF autoTable columnWidth wrap cuts table off

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDF to generate a PDF from an HTML table and jsPDF is great, expect I am having one issue, when I try to wrap the columnWidth, my table gets cut off :(

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', "a0");
var tbl = $('#cost-matrix-table').clone();
tbl.find('tr:nth-child(1)').remove();
tbl.find('tr:nth-child(1)').remove();
tbl.find('tr:nth-child(2)').remove();
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(tbl.get(0));

doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
    startY: 40,
    margin: {
        top: 40
    },
    addPageContent: function (data) {
        doc.setFontSize(28);
        doc.setTextColor(0);
        doc.setFontStyle('bold');
        doc.text("Losani Homes Cost Matrix " + $("#dropdown").val(), 500, 30);
    },
    styles: {
        fontSize: 20,
        overflow: 'linebreak',
        columnWidth: 'wrap',
    },
    theme: 'grid'
});

doc.save("Report.pdf");
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your autotable creation part into below code

```
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
        startY: 40,
        margin: {
            top: 40
        },
    addPageContent: function (data) {
doc.setFontSize(28);
doc.setTextColor(0);
doc.setFontStyle('bold');
doc.text("Losani Homes Cost Matrix " + $("#dropdown").val(), 500, 30);
},
styles: {
fontSize: 20,
overflow: 'linebreak'
},
columnWidth: 'wrap',
columnStyles:{
  0: {
    columnWidth: 100
  },
  1: {
    columnWidth: 100
  }, 
  2: {
    columnWidth: 100
  },
  3: {
    columnWidth: 100
  },
  4: {
    columnWidth: 100
  }
},
theme: 'grid'
});
```